# Select the id in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to make a searchable dropdown and I've finally reached asyncSelect to bind with API but I have a Problem
this is my code

```
const [isClearable, setIsClearable] = useState(true);
 const [isSearchable, setIsSearchable] = useState(true);
 const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
 const [isRtl, setIsRtl] = useState(false);
const [DeliveryDropDown, setDeliveryDropDown] = useState("");

 const handleSelectDeliveryDd = (event) => {
   setDeliveryDropDown(event);
  
 };
const loadOptions=async (searchValue,callback) => {
   const response = await fetch(
     `.../DeliveryCost?DeliveryCost_like=${searchValue}&BranchId=${user.BranchId}&Profile=${user.Profile}`,
     {
       headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer mmm`,
       },

       cache: "no-store",
     }
   );
   const json = await response.json();
   callback(json.map(i=>({label:i.deliveryCost , value:i.areaId })))
  
 }
<AsyncSelect required value={DeliveryDropDown} onChange={handleSelectDeliveryDd} 
className="basic-single" classNamePrefix="select"
isDisabled={isDisabled} isLoading={isLoading} isClearable={isClearable} isRtl={isRtl}
isSearchable={isSearchable} name="Location" loadOptions={loadOptions} defaultOptions />
```

1.I want to search By DeliveryCost but it shows all options not filtered options ...
2.and I want to select just the value in handleSelectDeliveryDd event, not all selected option now selected like this {label: 'التكلفة:4.000', value: '561'}

I hope you got it

Comment: Does the variable "json" contains all options or filtered options? (try to console log it). If it contains all options, then you have an API problem, it's not related to react-select. For 2), you can change your code to "onChange={({value}) => handleSelectDeliveryDd(value)}"

Comment: for 2. Now it's actually selecting the value but it's not showing the label that I selected in the dropdown ... excuse me but I'm fresh in react

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you describe for point 2. Maybe you should add details to your question. For point 1, did you add console.log(json); after await response.json()?